# VBA - Sending http request within webpage

Tags: vba, excel, xmlhttprequest

Our company uses a software which opens its applications through a website. I'm trying to use VBA to automate the process of opening a few applications.

After researching, I found out that the website uses a GET request to open each application. 
What I want to do is:
1) Open the website and login;
2) Send the GET request to open the application;

I can open and login just fine, my code is below:

```
Sub Test()

Dim xhrRequest As XMLHTTP60    
Set xhrRequest = New XMLHTTP60

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.Navigate ("http://websitelogin/")

    While ie.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
    Wend

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

    ie.document.forms(0).all("txtUsername").Value = "login"
    ie.document.forms(0).all("txtPassword").Value = "password"
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    ie.document.forms(0).all("btn-enter").Click

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

    xhrRequest.Open "GET", "http://getrequest", False 'found out that this _
    is the request made on the browser's developer tools

    xhrRequest.send

End Sub
```

Nothing happens after the request is sent. How to know if it's really being requested?

Comment: Have you tried going through your code with **F8** and checking what is happening? http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx Furthermore, it is a good practice to mention the additional libaries you are using in your code when giving code with early binding. In your case you are using **Microsoft XML**

Comment: Yes, the code works until the part I send the request, but doesn't give me any errors. I tried going under the network tab of ie's developer tools to see if the request is being sent but it's not.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use VBA to click on whatever element you'd normally click on to launch the application?

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. Had to hard code a bit but it worked!